# Qt/ PyQt - common code for document reading and writing

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I have written an application using Qt (C++) that creates and
maintains a document. There is a class in my program that encapsulates
this document and knows how to stream it etc. I want to produce a
small application using PyQt that manipulates these documents. What is
the best (by which I mean easiest to implement) way to expose/ reuse
this C++ class so I can access the documents in my PyQt script? I really don't want to duplicate the existing code in python. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move your class into a shared library, then use [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/index.html) to create bindings for Python. It's surprisingly easy, and it's the same tool that is used to create PyQt, so it has full support of Qt features. The only problem I've encountered with it is that marshaling/unmarshaling is pretty slow, so if your class requires a lot of calls or callbacks, it may cause performance problems.

Comment: thanks Sergey - I shall try this; speed isnt an important factor so this could be ideal.

Comment: oh. sip doesn't seem as straightforward as I had hoped! I have done it using boost python. this has the advantage that the python user of my files doesn't have to use pyqt but can just use regular old python. I dont need to expose any QTish ness from C++ so this is kinda nice. When I have a week out i shall revisit SIP -- it looks very interesting - thanks again.

Comment: @jolyon, the only trouble with SIP is that you have to write those *.sip files. They usually can be made from C++ headers with little modifications, though. The configuration script I usually copy from some example and modify a little, as it is quite daunting to write one from scratch. After that, it's just a matter of doing configure and make. By the way, SIP doesn't force you to use PyQt either. It just supports it natively, but it can be used for simple C/C++ libraries too, I have done that.